# For loop won't increment

Tags: c++

The for loop does not increment, it only does the first loop, I am trying to do the standard deviation equation, but when it comes to that for loop it produces a wrong result

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 6;
double nums[SIZE] = { 6,5,43,4,7,9 };
double s;
double av;
int i;
double sum = 0;

double average() {
    //av is to get the average of the array
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        sum += nums[i];
    }
    av = static_cast<double>(sum / (SIZE));
    return av;
}

double deviation() {
    double nominator;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        nominator += pow(nums[i] - average(), 2);
    }
    double inside = static_cast<double>(sum / SIZE);
    s = sqrt(inside);
    return s;
}
// The code works, but there is a problem with the deviation, which outputs the wrong result, line 21 for loop does not affect the nominator

int main() {
    cout << "Numbers: ";
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        nums[i];
        cout << nums[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Average: " << average() << endl;
    cout << "Standard Deviation: " << deviation() << endl;
}
```

Comment: `deviation` doesn't work right. It operates on an uninitialized `nominator`.

Comment: What is the pupose of `nums[i];` statement in the loop in `main` ?

Comment: `static_cast<double>(sum/SIZE)` seems extremely heavy-handed. Do you mean `sum /  SIZE`, as `sum` is already a `double`?

Comment: nums[i] in main so that when it runs,  it shows all the numbers in the array

Comment: @MohammedAl-Khater I understood this is the purpose of `cout <<nums[i]<< ' ';`. But I was referring to the line just before it.

Comment: `nominator` is uninitialized, modified, and never used. `deviation` returns the square root of the average.

Comment: how is nominator uninitialized? I would appreciate it if you can tell me how to fix it

Comment: You need: `double nominator = 0;`. C++ does not initialize variables to 0 by default.

Comment: Recommendation: Step through this code with a debugger and watch what happens. Keep an eye out for where the program begins to deviate from the expected.

Comment: i tried double nominator=0 , but still the same wrong result

Comment: If you do not give a local variable a value, you cannot predict what value it will have. Some explanation here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Comment: That is a necessary step, but ask yourself, "Where in the function is `nominator` used? How does it contribute to the returned value?"

Comment: I figured my mistake by ignoring nominator, but the problem is, that it still produces another wrong result, I don't want to be a burden, thank you all I appreciate it

Comment: I reiterate my recommendation that you take advantage of whatever debugger came with your development tools to run the program line-by-line. If you do all of the math on paper step by step as you execute the program you can compare your results against the program's and see where you disagree. Once you can see the problem, it's usually not long before you see the solution.

Comment: [Here is a piece on how to use the debugger that comes with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022). Other debuggers will be very similar, merely changing a few names and moving the buttons around.

Answer (score 2):

I have corrected the function deviation(). Now it works ok. It was a copy-paste error. You were using the same code for both average() and deviation(). Also the variable nominator was uninitialized and you were calling average() unnecessarily in a loop. Also its cheaper to square manually than using a pow() function.

```
double deviation() {
    double nominator=0;
    double avg = average();
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        nominator += ((nums[i] - avg)*(nums[i] - avg));
    }
    double inside = static_cast<double>(nominator / SIZE);
    s = sqrt(inside);
    return s;
}
```